# Convert String array to string back to string array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I converted a string array to string using `Arrays.toString(variable)` and saved it in a session. Now I want to convert it back to a string array. How do I do that?

I was hoping if there's a way to do it in a simpler way, like parsing it to string array.

Here's a sample of the string. It is separated by a comma.

```
[Any, Resolved (1), ANS MACH / LEFT MSG (1)]
```

Update:
I've been advised not to use `toString` to serialize array. But since I'm dealing with simple array, I still opted to use it.

Comment: `toString` should not be used for serialization/deserialization. Find a better tool (eg. JSON).

Comment: Why don't you save array directly in session?

Comment: @Pshemo im new to java so all I know is that I can only save a string, int and boolean to session. I haven't tried saving an array.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I was thinking it's fine to use tostring since I'm not dealing with long/large arrays.

Comment: @user3360031 - Can your strings contain commas?

Comment: Can `null` and `"null"` occur in the array.

Comment: @AndyThomas nope. that's one reason why I used tostring..correct me if I'm wrong though

Comment: @fabian nope. I made a checker to exclude null or empty string

Comment: That constraint is worth mentioning in the question. Otherwise, multiple String[] arrays could map to the same String, and there would not be a reverse function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the individual strings might themselves include a comma followed by a space, then this would not be feasible. Multiple String[] arrays could map to the same flat String, and an inverse function would not exist.

However, you note in a comment that your strings cannot include the comma separator. You can split the flat string back into the original substrings, using ", " (comma,space) as a separator.

APIs that support this include the standard Java [`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method, and Guava's [`Splitter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) class.

Here's an example with Java's `split()` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] strs = new String[] { "Foo", "Bar", "Baz" };

    String joined = Arrays.toString( strs );

    String joinedMinusBrackets = joined.substring( 1, joined.length() - 1);

    // String.split()
    String[] resplit = joinedMinusBrackets.split( ", "); 

    for ( String s : resplit ) {
        System.out.println( s );
    }

}
```

And here's an example with Guava's `Splitter` class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] strs = new String[] { "Foo", "Bar", "Baz" };

    String joined = Arrays.toString( strs );

    String joinedMinusBrackets = joined.substring( 1, joined.length() - 1);

    // Guava Splitter class
    List<String> resplitList = Splitter.on( ", " ).splitToList( joinedMinusBrackets );

    for ( String s : resplitList ) {
        System.out.println( s );
    }
}
```

Comment: I would use Base64 to encode and decode the strings to avoid any problems.

Answer (score 1):

I guess [that's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13271503/converting-array-string-to-string-and-back-in-java) the answer you're searching for. Briefly, it's about using serialization with apache [codecs](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/) for encoding/decoding objects. I don't want to do copy/paste from another answer, so I'll give you only the code sample in case link changes someday.
Here it is:

```
  // serialize
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    new ObjectOutputStream(out).writeObject(yourArray);

 //encode
    String encodeString = new String(Hex.encodeHex(out.toByteArray()));

 // deserialize
    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(Hex.decodeHex(yourString.toCharArray()));
    String yourArray = Arrays.toString((String[]) new ObjectInputStream(in).readObject());
}
// And then you could use `String#split()` method to convert string to array.
```

Another option is to use something like [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) JSON library, with Gson, you can convert any java object to a json string and then convert it back. Example code may looks like this:

```
//Put an array (or any other object to gson object
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(yourArray);

// Retrieve your object from gson
Gson gson = new Gson();
Array array = gson.fromJson(json, Array.class);
```

For more details you look [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/) article.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution (assuming that we are talking about Java EE's [HttpSession](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html)) would be not placing `String` representing array, but array itself via [`setAttribute(String name, Object value)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setAttribute-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) so as you see `value` can be any `Object`, not only `String`.

DEMO using `List<String>` instead of `String[]` (may not be perfect but should get the idea):

```
@WebServlet("/SessionDemo")
public class SessionDemo extends HttpServlet {


    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
        request.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        List<String> list = (List<String>) session.getAttribute("list");

        printList(out, list);
        printForm(out);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
        request.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();

        List<String> list = (List<String>) session.getAttribute("list");

        if (list == null){
            list = new ArrayList<>();
            session.setAttribute("list", list);
        }
        list.add(request.getParameter("item"));

        printList(out, list);
        printForm(out);

    }

    private void printList(PrintWriter out, List<String> list) {
        out.println("current items:");
        if (list != null){
            out.println("<ul>");
            for (String item : list){
                out.append("<li>").append(item).println("</li>");
            }
            out.println("</ul>");
        }else{
            out.println("list is empty");
        }
        out.println("<hr/>");
    }

    private void printForm(PrintWriter out){
        out.println(
                "<form action='./SessionDemo' method='post'>"
                + "<input type='text' name='item'/>"
                + "<input type='submit' value='add to list'/>"
                + "</form>"
        );
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you always wants string operation with this kinda sting `split()` is what you need:

```
public static void main(String []args){
    String string = "[Any, Resolved (1), ANS MACH / LEFT MSG (1)]";
    String[] parts = string.split(",");// your string Array
    int i=0;

    for(; i< parts.length; i++)
        System.out.println(parts[i]);
 }
```

If your string contains `[` and `]` also. Then you would need `.replace()`

---

Best practice to use `JSON` for Response/Request processing.