# Serialization of String[]: how to convert String value to String[] one?

Tags: java, serialization, containers

here is code for main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Container container= new Container();
        Serializator serializator = new Serializator();
        container.setvalue("1st val");
        serializator.serialization(container);
    }
```

here is code for container

```
public class Container implements Serializable {

      
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        /**
         * Holds the elements of a container.
         */
        private String[] values;
        
     
       public String[] getvalue() {
        return values;
           
       }
       public void setvalue(String[] values) {
           this.values=values;
       }
    }
```

here is code for a serializator

```
public class Serializator {
    public boolean serialization(Container container) {
        boolean flag=false;
        File file= new File("C:/conatiner.data");
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos= new FileOutputStream(file);
            if(fos != null) {
                oos= new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                oos.writeObject(container);
                flag=true;
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(oos != null) {
                try {
                    oos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return flag;
    }
}
```

Well, the program should be working in a following way: you create a container that has an array of strings,(you can set the values in it) and then the program must serialize it. but the problem is that the tutorial worked with the String value, but not the String[] one. how can i make it understand the String[] value and insert it?
The crashlog is the following

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method setvalue(String[]) in the type Container is not applicable for the arguments (String)

    at ua.khpi.oop.taradai06.program6.main(program6.java:7)

"container.setvalue("1st val");"
```

Comment: [`"1st val".split(" ")`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,int))!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to accept both `String` and `String[]` as an input parameter to `Container::setvalue` method, the *varargs* should be used, then a single String is accepted as an array consisting of one element.

Also, Java naming conventions for getters/setters of Java Beans specify to capitalize the property names after get/set verb: [Getter and setter method names are composed of the word get or set, respectively, plus the property name with the first character of each word capitalized](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/javaserver-pages-3rd/0596005636/ch20s01s01.html), so the methods should be names as `getValues/setValues`:

```java
// Container class
public void setValues(String... values) {
    this.values = values;
}
```

Then this method can be invoked as follows without additional overloading:

```
container.setValues(); // empty array new String[0]
container.setValues("a string"); // new String[1]{"a string"}
container.setValues("a", "b"); // new String[2]{"a",  "b"}
container.setValues(new String[]{"1", "2", "3"}); // common array
```

Answer (score 2):

First, let's focus on the bug:
In the container, you promised you will send an array of string in the function `setValue`, but you are sending a single string.
There are two things you could do;

- keep the `container` code as it is and send `array of strings` from main
- Change the `container` code and let `setValue` get a single string value and `add` it to the `values` array

And you main question related with serialisation please check [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13271503/converting-array-string-to-string-and-back-in-java) post

Answer (score 0):

If you promised you'll use the String[] parameter, then you should note that.
The following version of using setvalue does this work perfectly

```
container.setvalue(new String[] {"1st val","2nd val","3rd val"});
```

Answer (score 0):

OK I hope I helped you look in the class "Container" in "setvalue" function, you gived it the parameter "1st value"(Its one string) but it needs a String array. So you can replace your code with this:

main class:

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Container container= new Container();
        Serializator serializator = new Serializator();
        container.setvalue("1st value", 0);
        serializator.serialization(container);
    }
}
```

Container class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Container implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    /**
     * Holds the elements of a container.
     */

    int AnyNumberYouWant = 100;

    private String[] values = new String[AnyNumberYouWant];


    public String[] getvalue() {
        return values;

    }
    public void setvalue(String value, int index) {
        this.values[index]=value;
    }
}
```

Serializator class

```
import java.io.*;

public class Serializator {
    public boolean serialization(Container container) {
        boolean flag=false;
        File file= new File("C:/Container/container.data");
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos= new FileOutputStream(file);
            if(fos != null) {
                oos= new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                oos.writeObject(container);
                flag=true;
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(oos != null) {
                try {
                    oos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return flag;
    }
}
```

And I solved another errors that was there in the code. So I tried it and worked correctly. I hope that I helped you.